# Create AND expression with OR and NOT

Tags: logic, operators, operator-keyword

For an assignment I have to write a Boolean formula equivalent to:

```
X = (A > 10) & (A < 20)
```

I can't use the `&` operator. A hint is given: use `OR` and `NOT`. I simply can't get my head around the problem and think it is impossible.

```
X = not(A<10) or not(A>20)
```

won't work because this would simply always be true. I tried a few other options but none of them will give the same result as the first formula. So, is this possible?

Comment: [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Substitution_form)

Comment: can you use && operator?

Comment: Nope, only AND OR NOT XOR, but the literal hint is; use OR and NOT

Answer (score 1):

The following equivalences hold in classical logic:

```
¬¬P      ≡ P         (Double Negation)
¬(P ∧ Q) ≡ ¬P ∨ ¬Q   (De Morgan's Law 1)
¬(P ∨ Q) ≡ ¬P ∧ ¬Q   (De Morgan's Law 2)
```

It follows that:

```
  P ∧ Q
≡ ¬¬(P ∧ Q)    (Double Negation Introduction)
≡ ¬(¬P ∨ ¬Q)   (De Morgan's Law 1)
```

In your case, we have:

```
  (N > 10) ∧ (N < 20)
≡ ¬¬((N > 10) ∧ (N < 20))    (Double Negation Introduction)
≡ ¬(¬(N > 10) ∨ ¬(N < 20))   (De Morgan's Law 1)
≡ ¬(N ≤ 10 ∨ N ≥ 20)         (Trichotomy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ocasa, indeed Morgan's law;

not(not(a>10) or not(a<20))